# Tried to synchronously call function {promiseMethodWrapper} from a different thread

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, rctbridge

This is the first time I'm trying the bridging of react-native and a native iOS app.

In my react-native iOS project, I've created a swift file (that created a bridging header) and in that swift file I've created a sample method to test first:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {

  @objc
  func testFunctionWithPromiseResolve(frame: Frame,
                                 resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                                 rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    
    var resp = [String:Any]() //Init Dictionary
    
    resp.updateValue(frame, forKey: "frame");
    resolve(resp);
    
  }

  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

}
```

In the bridging header file I have imports only:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import <VisionCamera/FrameProcessorPlugin.h>. //from react-native-vision-camera
#import <VisionCamera/Frame.h> //from react-native-vision-camera
```

Then I created an objective-c file named `MyModule.m` and in it, I've added:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface
RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject);
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(testFunctionWithPromiseResolve:
                  (Frame *)frame
                  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock *)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock *)reject);
                  
@end
```

Then in react-native, I have a `Home.js` where I'm going to access this method.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, useCameraDevices, useFrameProcessor } from 'react-native-vision-camera';

import 'react-native-reanimated'

function Home(props) {

    const devices = useCameraDevices();
    const device = devices.back;

    const { MyModule } = NativeModules;

    const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {

        'worklet';

        let res = MyModule.testFunctionWithPromiseResolve(frame);
        console.log(res);

        // .then((res) => {
        //     console.log(res);
        // }).catch((e) => {
        //     console.log(e);
        // })

    })

//... My other code is just UI-related in which I'm calling the frameProcessor in <Camera... using its prop frameProcessor={frameProcessor} as per react-native-vision-camera documentation.
```

As per my understanding, we handle a Promise with `then` and `catch` as I assume this is what we'll be getting from `RCTPromiseResolveBlock` but that was not working so I just simply tried `console.log(res);` and it prints `undefined`.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Tried to synchronously call function {promiseMethodWrapper} from a different thread.

Possible solutions are:
a) If you want to synchronously execute this method, mark it as a Worklet
b) If you want to execute this method on the JS thread, wrap it using runOnJS

reanimated::REAIOSErrorHandler::raiseSpec()
    REAIOSErrorHandler.mm:18
reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()::operator()()
decltype(static_cast<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()&>(fp)()) std::__1::__invoke<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()&>(reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()&)
void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()&>(reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()&)
std::__1::__function::__alloc_func<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'(), std::__1::allocator<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()>, void ()>::operator()()
std::__1::__function::__func<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'(), std::__1::allocator<reanimated::ErrorHandler::raise()::'lambda'()>, void ()>::operator()()
std::__1::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()() const
std::__1::function<void ()>::operator()() const
invocation function for block in vision::VisionCameraScheduler::scheduleOnUI(std::__1::function<void ()>)
F14F0161-E0DE-3D9C-851E-AD12F95A3073
F14F0161-E0DE-3D9C-851E-AD12F95A3073
F14F0161-E0DE-3D9C-851E-AD12F95A3073
F14F0161-E0DE-3D9C-851E-AD12F95A3073
F14F0161-E0DE-3D9C-851E-AD12F95A3073
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

I've `worklet` defined in the `useFrameProcessor`.

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the `obj-c` method to:

```
@objc(testFunctionWithPromiseResolve:resolver:rejecter:)
  func testFunctionWithPromiseResolve(_ frame: Frame,
                                 resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                                 rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {...
```

and the in JS I did:

```
let module = NativeModules.MyModule;

const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {

        'worklet';
        //let module = NativeModules.MyModule; //didnt work either
        console.log(module.testFunctionWithPromiseResolve(frame));

    })
```

But I get the same error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Luckily I found the problem.

1. Custom `Frame Processor Plugins` need to be completed according to the document, the document address is [Creating Frame Processor Plugins](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors-plugins-ios), native-side customize code that you need to use the `VISION_EXPORT_FRAME_PROCESSOR` export definition plugin, and using `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE` and `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` will fails.
2. You need to export custom plug-in methods on the js side, the document address is [Expose your Frame Processor Plugin to JS](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors-plugins-final), as follows:

```
import type { Frame } from 'react-native-vision-camera'

/**
 * Scans QR codes.
 */
export function scanQRCodes(frame: Frame): string[] {
  'worklet'
  return __scanQRCodes(frame)
}
```

but now ,this will be `__scanQRCodes`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanQRCodes'],
      },
    ],
```

you have to restart metro-bundler for changes in the `babel.config.js` file to take effect.

3: you must be restarted project to take effect.

My code is as follows:

I customized a Ojective-C `frame Processor Plugins` named `MyModuleFrameProcessPlugin.m`, the code is implemented as follows:

```
#import <VisionCamera/FrameProcessorPlugin.h>
#import <VisionCamera/Frame.h>

@interface MyModuleFrameProcessPlugin : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyModuleFrameProcessPlugin

static inline id myCustomPlugin(Frame* frame, NSArray* arguments) {
  CVPixelBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(frame.buffer);
  NSLog(@"myCustomPlugin: %zu x %zu Image. Logging %lu parameters:", CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer), (unsigned long)arguments.count);
  
  for (id param in arguments) {
    NSLog(@"myCustomPlugin:   -> %@ (%@)", param == nil ? @"(nil)" : [param description], NSStringFromClass([param classForCoder]));
  }
  
  return @{
    @"myCustomPlugin_str": @"Test",
    @"myCustomPlugin_bool": @true,
    @"myCustomPlugin_double": @5.3,
    @"myCustomPlugin_array": @[
      @"Hello",
      @true,
      @17.38
    ]
  };
}
VISION_EXPORT_FRAME_PROCESSOR(myCustomPlugin)
@end
```

Create a new js plugin named `ExamplePlugin.ts`, the code is as follows:

```
/* global __myCustomPlugin */
import type { Frame } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
declare let _WORKLET: true | undefined;
export function cusPlugin(frame: Frame): string[] {
  'worklet';
  if (!_WORKLET) throw new Error('my_custom_plugin must be called from a frame processor!');

  // @ts-expect-error because this function is dynamically injected by VisionCamera
  return __myCustomPlugin(frame, 'hello my_custom_plugin!', 'parameter2', true, 42, { test: 0, second: 'test' }, ['another test', 500]);
}
```

The `babel.config.js` file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__myCustomPlugin']
      }
    ]
  ],
};
```

The plugin import code is as follows:

```
import {cusPlugin} from './ExamplePlugin';
```

The calling code is as follows:

```
  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet';
    const value = cusPlugin(frame);
    console.log(`Return Values: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
  }, []);
  //Use in Camera is  frameProcessor={frameProcessor}
```

I tested my code and it is ok, I hope it can help you.